# how to send 5 strings from android app to website(local host)

Tags: android, json, localhost

i have taken help from few sites and developed a code for sending data from app to website . but this code is giving error . help me to send the 5 from my  application form to website.

public class MainActivityServer extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
Button send1;
TextView name;
TextView number;
TextView email;
TextView suggestion;

 // url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_server);
    send1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Send);
    name= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.T1);
    number= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.T2);
    email= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.T3);
    suggestion= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.T4);

    send1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}   
public class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

         String name = name.getText().toString();
         String number = number.getText().toString();
         String email = email.getText().toString();
         String suggestion = suggestion.getText().toString();
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", number));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", email));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", suggestion));

         // getting JSON Object
         // Note that create product url accepts POST method
         JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                 "POST", params);

         // check log cat fro response
         Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

         // check for success tag
         try {
             int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

             if (success == 1) {
                 // successfully created product
                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                 startActivity(i);

                 // closing this screen
                 finish();
             } else {
                 // failed to create product
             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return null;
     }

     /**
      * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
      * **/




    //end postData()
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_server, menu);
    return true;
}

}}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share with us your error trace (extract of Logcat) when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are an error here:

```
String url_create_product = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php";
```

This is the url to the server of the androidhive.com.

You need to replace them by your localhost or your own server.

Make sure that you have modified the manifest.xml file , you need to set the internet permission as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidhive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <application
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
        android:icon="@drawable/logo4"
        android:label="@string/app_name_phone" >
....
....
....
    </application>
....
....
....
....
....
....
    <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: i cant post a picture , so cant post logcat pic .  but will tell u the errors. wait

Comment: 1.JSONParser cannot be resolved to a type
2.Log cannot be resolve MainActivityServer.java 
3.The method getText() is undefined for the type String(in line 73,10,9,72,8,70,71)

Comment: go to your manifest file , just add :<!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> befor the </manifest> tag